# How to pass a variable to HTML page from JS code , after ajax success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Consider the ajax request  :

```
var idNumber = $("#Field_1").val();
var servletUrl = "someURL"; // some url goes here

$.ajax({ 
    url: servletUrl,
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false, 
    data: { }, 
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        window.location = "./replyToYou.html";
    }
    , error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err){
        alert('text status '+textStatus+', err '+err + " " + JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
    }
});
```

How can I pass , on success `idNumber` to `replyToYou.html` , and how can I grab it in `replyToYou.html` ?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to different solution:

1- first is using queryString:

```
success: function(data){
    alert(data);
    window.location = "./replyToYou.html?idNumber=" + idNumber;
}
```

then read it from querystring using this function (I use it as a querystring helper which is originally created in this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)):

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
getParameterByName("idNumber");
```

2- the other option is using `localStorage`:

```
success: function(data){
    alert(data);
    localStorage.setItem("idNumber",idNumber);
    window.location = "./replyToYou.html";
}
```

and get it at the other page like:

```
localStorage.getItem("idNumber")
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong , but using the `1st` method you suggested would cause the user to see in the address bar the details that are passed ?

Comment: @ron: that's right, but you can use Base64 or whatever, to encode it. I myself usually go with the second solution.

Comment: Yes , I get something like this in the browser tab : `/register_replyToYou.html?idNumber=44444444444444444444`

Comment: @ron: then using the function I have mentioned, get it in your code like `alert(getParameterByName("idNumber"))`.

Comment: @ron: let me know if it was helpful or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot , first of all. Second , please pay attention that the `idnumber` is still presented on the browser tab . I guess I'll deal with it later ...

Answer (score 1):

edit code js in success section :

```
success: function(data){
    alert(data);
   window.location.href = "./replyToYou.html?idNumber=" + idNumber;
}
```

Comment: It's a HTML page so you have to have some way to get idNumber from the URL string.